# How can yum download packages from a non-existent base URL?

Tags: google-chrome, yum

In order to get the Chrome browser running on RHEL 7.5 I found this `yum` repo file that helped me install the required package:

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

Now the installation via `yum install google-chrome` worked perfectly fine, but I wonder how that's possible, because the baseurl (and any shorter path segment of it) returns an error "404 Not Found". How is it possible that `yum` downloads packages given this repo file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like google just return a `404` rather than a directory listing.

If you browse directly to: `https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml` the correct `xml` file is downloaded and behaves normally. I'd guess if you put the full & correct path to a given `.rpm` you would be able to download that manually as well.